# Leaflet request non-existing tiles despite maxNativeZoom being set

Tags: leaflet

I have this leaflet map with a `tileLayer` where `maxNativeZoom` is not working for some reason. If I zoom in further than the zoom level it has tiles for, and then try to pan, it requests non-existing tiles from the server. I can see it in the network console.

Not only is it requesting tiles at zoom level 5 when I set `maxNativeZoom: 4`, it also request tiles of zoom level 40.
And `errorTileUrl` isn't working either.

[image: This is at zoom level 4]
[image: and this at zoom level 5]

*edit*
I managed to make the map publicly accessible, so you can see it [here](https://fictionalmaps.com/audience-map/?creator=5&map=testMap)
*/edit*

I copied the code from another leaflet map of mine (where it is working) and only changed things (like paths) that should not interfere with `maxNativeZoom` in any way.

Here is the relevant code, hopefully one of you can spot what I'm missing:

```
    w = 4096;
    h = 4096;
    tileDepth = 4;

    /*
    =============================================================================
    // Conversion from (x, y) raster image coordinates to equivalent of latLng
    =============================================================================
    */  

    var yx = L.latLng;
    var xy = function(x, y) {
      if (L.Util.isArray(x)) { // When doing xy([x, y]);
        return yx(x[1], x[0]);
      }
      return yx(y, x); // When doing xy(x, y);
    };

    /**
    =============================================================================
    Define basic map parameters and custom CRS by extending CRS.Simple
    =============================================================================
     */

    var minZoom = 2;
    var maxZoom = 12;
    var img = [
      w, 
      h 
    ];
    var transformationCoefficient = Math.pow(2, tileDepth);

    L.CRS.MySimple = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
      //                      coefficients: a      b    c     d
      transformation: new L.Transformation(1/transformationCoefficient, 0, 1/transformationCoefficient, 0) // Compute a and c coefficients so that  tile 0/0/0 is from [0, 0] to [img]
    });

    var bounds = [xy(0, 0), xy(img)];

    /*
    =============================================================================
    Create the map itself
    =============================================================================
    */

    var map = L.map("map", {
      crs: L.CRS.MySimple, // http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-crs
      maxBounds: bounds, // http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-maxbounds
      minZoom: minZoom,
      maxZoom: maxZoom,
      attributionControl: false,
      zoomControl: false    //disable zoom control at standard position - we'll add a new one later
    }).setView([w/2, h/2], 0);; //this should center the map in our 1024x1024 div


    //add zoom control at new position
    L.control.zoom({
        position:'topright'
    }).addTo(map);

    /*
    =============================================================================
    Import tiles
    =============================================================================
    */


    L.tileLayer(mapPath + 'tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        bounds: bounds, // http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#gridlayer-bounds
        noWrap: true,
        minZoom: minZoom,
        maxZoom: maxZoom,
        maxNativeZoom: tileDepth,   //how deep the actual map tiles go
        errorTileUrl: imgDir + 'error_tile.png',
        attribution: mapAttribution
      }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Sorry for the double post - stack exchange did not show me my last question as posted. That's why I reposted this morning.

Comment: For some reason I still can't find my post from last night... Anyway, @IvanSanchez said he could not reproduce it. The only thing I can think of is, that it is some kind of interaction with wordpress, as this map sits inside a wordpress website. But I don't know how to go about debugging this, as the console does not tell me anything helpful except the weird zoom level of 40 that leaflet is requesting. You can see it in action here: https://fictionalmaps.com/audience-map/?creator=5&map=testMap

Comment: I've checked your online map and there's really something strange going on when you pan map at zooms above max native zoom. I'll check it this evening.

Comment: Interesting. Something, somewhere (wordpress?), is changing the `z` property of the tiles into a string, and [this line here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/1d09819922f592cd0fcdf37eb1fc263544a8bab6/src/layer/tile/GridLayer.js#L435) is making `"4" + 2` into zoom level `42`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing...

```
tileDepth = document.getElementById('zoom').value;
```

...and that'll set `tileDepth` to a **string** containing a numeric value, rather than a number. Then, you feed that string as the value of the `maxNativeZoom` option of a `L.TileLayer` and later, deep in the bowerls of Leaflet, [a line of code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/1d09819922f592cd0fcdf37eb1fc263544a8bab6/src/layer/tile/GridLayer.js#L435) runs `z + 2` is, turning your `maxNativeZoom`  of `"4"` into `"42"` (because `"4" + 2 = "42"` in JS) rather than `4 + 2 = 6`.

Remember, the [`maxNativeZoom` option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#gridlayer-maxnativezoom) **must** be a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type) and not a [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type).

The responsibility of casting strings into numbers falls on to you, and a few of the ways of doing so are...

```
tileDepth = Number(document.getElementById('zoom').value);
```

or

```
tileDepth = parseInt(document.getElementById('zoom').value);
```

or

```
L.tileLayer(tilePath, {
    maxNativeZoom: Number(tileDepth),
    /* etc */
});
```

...amongst others.

Comment: How did you find `tileDepth = document.getElementById('zoom').value;` statement? I got completely lost in WordPress mumbo jumbo.

Comment: That was it! Typecasting... my old foe! Totally missed that the variable type got lost (or rather changed to String) by using the DOM way to get the value from php to javascript. 
Thank you so much!

Comment: @TomazicM Just plain ol' debugging: tracing back references to the variable assignments involving the troublesome string. I guess I gained JS debugging superpowers over the last few years :-P